# Using angular-ui-router, how to prevent controller from reloading?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I don't know if prevent the controller from reloading is exactly what I need.

I have the following scenario:

A view called `client.list.html` and it's controller `ClientListController` (list clients).

A view called `client.html` and it's controller `ClientController` (create and edit client)

On the client list, there's a button to edit the clients and some pagination.
What I want to do is:

When the user clicks to edit the client and go back to the list, the information (like selected client, current page and results) should be there still. But the controller gets reloaded and everything is lost.

Comment: Can you provide what you already have in terms of code? It helps :)

Answer (score 1):

As of my understanding you want to let the data binded to the view still there, correct me if this is wrong.

I had a similar problem where I had to keep the certain data on the view once loaded even if the view is reloaded. In this case you can bind the data to the view through `$rootscope`. There is only one `$rootscope` for the application and will not reload even if the view is reloaded.